# laravel 5.4 route view crash error

Tags: html, laravel, routes

So there's a problem with my view, and i think it's because there's something wrong with route, although i think it's actually fine but i can't seem to find it,

for example when the route is like this

```
Route::get('/test', 'Product\MuslimController@show')->name('muslim.details');
```

the view is like this

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjizf.png)

but when the route is like this

```
Route::get('/test/test', 'Product\MuslimController@show')->name('muslim.details');
```

it became like this

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xBzY.png)

can anybody tell me why this happens?, thanks

this is my view:

usernav.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{{-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> --}}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>Amazia Collection</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      {{-- <ul class="navbar-nav"> --}}
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('main') }}">Home</a>
        </li>
        @if(Auth::check() == false)                      
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('login') }}">Login</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
        @else
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-4">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown d-flex flex-row-reverse">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Halo, {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              {{-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> --}}
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                           document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
                  <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                  </form>
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      @endif

      {{-- <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div> --}}
  </nav>
</header>

<main role="main">

  @yield('content')

</main>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@yield('script')

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/holder.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('form-signin');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
          }, false);
        });
      }, false);
    })();
</script>
```

details.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.usernav')

@section('content')

<link href="{{asset('css/details.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-  awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="container-fliud">
            <div class="wrapper row">
                <div class="preview col-md-6">

                    <div class="preview-pic tab-content">
                        {{-- <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1"><img src="image/{{$image['img_picture']}}" /></div> --}}
                      {{-- <div class="tab-pane active" id="pic-1"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div> --}}
                     {{--  <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-2"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-3"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-4"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div>
                      <div class="tab-pane" id="pic-5"><img src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div> --}}
                    </div>
                    {{-- <ul class="preview-thumbnail nav nav-tabs">
                      <li class="active"><a data-target="#pic-1" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/126" /></a></li>
                      <li><a data-target="#pic-2" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/126" /></a></li>
                      <li><a data-target="#pic-3" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/126" /></a></li>
                      <li><a data-target="#pic-4" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/126" /></a></li>
                      <li><a data-target="#pic-5" data-toggle="tab"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/126" /></a></li>
                    </ul> --}}

                </div>
                <div class="details col-md-6">
                    <h3 class="product-title">Code Name: </h3>
                    {{-- <div class="rating">
                        <div class="stars">
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="review-no">41 reviews</span>
                    </div> --}}
                    {{-- <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p> --}}
                    <p class="product-description">Harga Grosir: </p>
                    <p class="product-description">Harga Eceran: </p>

                    {{-- <h4 class="price">current price: <span>$180</span></h4> --}}
                    {{-- <p class="vote"><strong>91%</strong> of buyers enjoyed this product! <strong>(87 votes)</strong></p> --}}
                    <h5 class="sizes">sizes:
                        <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">s</span>
                        <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="medium">m</span>
                        <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="large">l</span>
                        <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="xtra large">xl</span>
                    </h5>
                    <h5 class="colors">colors:
                        <span class="color orange" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
                        <span class="color green"></span>
                        <span class="color blue"></span>
                    </h5>
                    <div class="action">
                        <a href="{{route('muslim.order')}}" class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">add to cart</a>
                        <button class="like btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

and this is the route

```
Route::prefix('muslim')->group(function(){

Route::get('', 'Product\MuslimController@main')->name('muslim.dashboard');

Route::get('{ID}', 'Product\MuslimController@details')->name('muslim.details');
 });
```

and this is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use App\Muslim;

class MuslimController extends Controller
{
    public function main(){
        $muslim = Muslim::all();
        return view('product.muslim.muslim', compact('muslim'));
}

public function details($id){

    $item = DB::table('muslims')->where('ID', $id)->first();
    return view('product.muslim.details', compact('item'));
}

}
```

Comment: This has something to do with styling. Check how you're adding css to your file.

Comment: Its not clear, what is your question here?

Comment: you mean like how i position my css link?

Comment: just add css file man. Make default blade for yourself.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: @C2486, so whenever i made multiple slash to the route for example like test/how/are/you, the design's always crash, but if i combine the route for example testhowareyou, the design goes back to normal

Comment: because you dont' have that route `test/how/are/you` ... What do you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

This isn't a Laravel problem, it's a simple HTML problem. Your stylesheet is being referenced relatively, which means the web browser determines the request url using the base path of the request plus the relative path. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
```

When you visit `http://example.com/test` your browser interprets the stylesheet reference as the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/app.css">
```

That's because `http://example.com/` is the base path. When you visit `http://example.com/test/test` your browser interprets the stylesheet reference as the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/test/app.css">
```

That's because `http://example.com/test/` is the base path. The solution is to use an absolute reference to the base path, not a relative reference, e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
```

Then when you visit any page on your website, it will always make the following request:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/app.css">
```

### The Laravel Way

Laravel provides an [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset) helper that you can use to generate a URL to your asset, e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('app.css') }}">
```

That would produce:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/app.css">
```

Comment: i'm also using @extends, and it looks like the view of the file that i extends doesn't connect to the css inside the view

Comment: @User9124 if you're still having problems then please update the question with your code. We can't help you without the code.

Comment: there, i add it